# Should SQLLite be closed after calling readable

Tags: android, sqlite

Do we need to close SQLite after getting it readable?I am new to Android.I tried to search but could not find Appropriate Solution. After some Research I found out Its necessary to close db after write able() but I am not sure about Readble()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always have to close Database after using it even if it's for reading it.

You just have to put :

```
close(db);
```

just after use it.